# Line chart from multiple tables in Excel 2013

Tags: worksheet-function, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have two sheets, "Graphs" and "Data".

In "Graphs" is a line chart with a single line that gets X and Y values from tables in "Data". I want the chart to be updated automatically when I add tables/values to the tables. The X values are incrementing by 1, and there is no system in the Y values. Every table has a number of elements, a position and a header, which is "Table" + the table number. Generally my tables are configured as follows:

[image: tables]

**I want the line chart to take all the X and Y values from table 1, then from table 2, table 3... and so on until there are no more tables.**

If this isn't possible please come with a suggestion of how I can present my data differently. This is an example of my tables, but they do actually have more Y values, and some of my line charts depends on the average, so I can't merge the tables. Given a general formula for the charts I will insert it into the other charts.

Comment: why do you need multiple tables? If there is something different about each table, you could combine them all and include an additional column to distinguish the values. This will make it easier to draw your charts, too.

Comment: That is a very good idea, and it can definitely solve my problem in a much cleaner way. The thing was the tables had different numbers of elements, but I see that doesn't matter.

Comment: Like most problems people have with line charts, you can fix your chart by making it into a scatter chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to write such a function, but the data can  be presented much cleaner as suggested by guitarthrower.

Make one giant table with columns for every item you want to track. You have a number of rows equal to the maxium number of elements for a single item. Thus if the tables before had different numbers of elements some of the cells for some items are blank. You then graph the values for a single item until you come to a blank cell.

The average for a single item can be taking of the whole column.